# Juction boxes and surface mount ceiling tiles

Tags: electrical

I understand that electrical junction boxes can be located above a suspended drop ceiling. I'm finishing a portion of my basement, and for height clearance purposes, I'd like to use a snap in grid system which puts the drop ceiling tiles directly against the joists. Can I still mount junction boxes for the lighting above this ceiling and be code compliant, like a normal suspended drop ceiling? The ceiling tiles snap in place and do not require any demolition or screw removal for access.

Comment: The usual idea is they need to be access by hand only, open a door, take down a picture, move a chair type of stuff.  Once a tool is needed or a wall(drywall) needs removing, that is a no-no.  If the ceiling tiles can be easily removed by hand(not punching a hole in the tile) it should be okay.

Comment: After they snap in do they snap out easily, or do they require a lever or become damaged when removed?

Comment: Snap outs, specifically the ceilinglink or ceilingmax systems.

Comment: @crip659 when you say "tool" does that include a screw-on access panel?

Comment: @Huesmann   I think it does.  A screw-on access panel with a door would be okay, but if you need to unscrew something to get to the box that is not okay.

Comment: @crip659 but you need to unscrew a standard junction box/outlet cover plate to access the wires inside.

Comment: @Huesmann  I don't write the code, but I imagine they consider the cover plate/light fixture screws to be a part of the junction box.  Those screws do no damage to a wall/ceiling(in most cases).  A junction box must have a cover on it, to prevent fingers/damage to the wires inside(except for work in the junction box).   I took your screw-on access panel as a panel screwed onto the wall that covers the box as decoration, like a mirror screwed onto the wall over the box.